# Numerical Solve in Java

Tags: java, numerical-methods, algebra, newtons-method

I'm looking to incorporate some sort of implementation of numerical solving for linear algebraic solutions in Java, like this:

5x + 4 = 2x + 3

Ideally, I would prefer to parse as little as possible, and avoid using traditional "human" methods of solutions (i.e. combine like terms, etc).  I've been looking into Newton's Method and plugging in values for x to approximate a solution.

I'm having trouble getting it to work though.

***Does anyone know the best general way to do this, and how it should be done in code (preferably Java)?***

**Additional**

In Netwon's Method, you iterate until the approximation is to acceptable accuracy.  The formula looks like this:

x1 = x0 - (f(x0) / (f '(x0))

where x1 is the next value for x in the iteration, and x0 is the current value (or starting guess if on first iteration).

What is f prime?  Assuming f(x0) is the function of your current x estimation, what expression does f'(x0) represent?

**Clarification**

*This is still a question of how to PROGRAM this math evaluation, not simply how to do the math.*

Comment: This sounds more like a maths question than a programming question, at present...

Comment: what is the question here?

Comment: If I remember correctly, f prime is the derivative of f.

Comment: And for linear equations, Newton's method is not really what you need.

Comment: Well part of the question is how to implement it in code, thus it is still a programming question.  It's rather simple math if you think about it, the real question is programming it.

The only code I can post is the current iteration loop I have.

Comment: This question is very much about programming.  I won't bother reopening because it has been answered, but some of you may want to read a little bit more thoroughly before throwing your "She's a witch" card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

f'(x0) is the *derivative* of f evaluated at x0.  You can compute an approximation to f' by evaluating:

```
f'(x0) ~ (f(x0+epsilon) - f(x0))/epsilon
```

for a suitably tiny value `epsilon` (because `f` is linear, any reasonable value of `epsilon` will give essentially the same result; for more general functions `f` the subtlety of choosing a good `epsilon` to use is entirely too subtle to be discussed in a S.O. post -- enroll in an upper-division undergraduate numerical analysis course).

However, since you want to avoid "human" methods, I should point out that for the specific case of linear equations, Newton's method always converges in a single iteration, and is in fact essentially equivalent to the usual algebraic solution technique.

To illustrate this, consider your example.  To use Newton's method, one needs to transform the equation so that it looks like f(x) = 0:

```
5x + 4 = 2x + 3
5x + 4 - (2x + 3) = 0
```

So `f(x) = 5x + 4 - (2x + 3)`.  The derivative of `f(x)` is `f'(x) = 5 - 2 = 3`.  If we start with an initial guess `x0 = 0`, then Newton's method gives us:

```
x1 = x0 - f(x0)/f'(x0)
   = 0 - (5*0 + 4 - (2*0 + 3))/3
   = 0 - (4-3)/3
   = -1/3
```

This is actually exactly the same operations that a human would use to solve the equation, somewhat subtly disguised.  Taking the derivative isolated the `x` terms (`5x - 2x = 3x`), and evaluating at zero isolated the terms without an `x` (`4-3 = 1`).  Then we divided the constant coefficient by the linear coefficient and negated to get `x`.

Comment: This seems to work very nicely.  I was about to ask about practical ways of finding the slope (derivative) when you updated it.  How much does it matter what I choose for epsilon?

Comment: For a linear function, it hardly matters at all -- assuming that you are using `double` to evaluate, so long as `epsilon` is within ~15 orders of magnitude of `x` you will get sane results.  For more general functions, it matters tremendously, and is an extremely subtle problem.

Comment: In code, how would you choose epsilon?  Fixed value, seed, etc?

Comment: If you're only going to be solving simple equations and aren't going to have extremely large or small values, set `epsilon = 1.0e-8` and call it a day.

Comment: Sound like a plan.  Unfortunately, I discovered a bug in my expression parser, so I will have to fix that before truly implementing this.  In the event that more complex equations come up, and the results begin to be inaccurate, should I just throw my hands up in defeat or is there a logical way to adjust the epsilon value?

Comment: Assuming that the expressions remain reasonably smooth (a technical mathematical term, but you might pretend that it means "nice"), and `x0` doesn't get too big or too small, you can stick with `1.0e-8`.  If you want to be more sophisticated, you can use something like `max(1.0e-8, abs(x*1.0e-8))` which will better handle cases where `x` gets to be very very large; beyond that point, this gets to be a very subtle question that requires a lot of careful mathematics.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you don't want to use some new algorithms or rewrite old algorithms, you can use [equation solver](http://code.google.com/p/equation-solver/).